Conan 2 recipe using user_toolchain in conan center
I'm trying to create a conan recipe that uses a custom toolchain to build a library but I didn't find a relevant example in the conan center recipes.
When building the library in my machine, I use a custom profile that looks like this:
include(default)
[conf]
tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:user_toolchain+=/home/myself/Arduino-CMake-Toolchain/Arduino-toolchain.cmake
[settings]
arch=armv7

But I'm not sure how I should go about doing this for a recipe that I want to add to conan center.
Is there a way to pass the user_toolchain programmatically from conanfile.py?
Am I expected to download the toolchain I need from my conanfile.py and then point to its relative location?

Toolchain files are for specific platforms, but the binaries built in ConanCenter are Linux/Windows/OSX ones, so the library submitted should be able to compile in at least one of them, with some of the default configurations supported by ConanCenter. It is not possible to build with something like Arduino in ConanCenter even if you provide a toolchain.cmake file because the Arduino tools will not be installed in ConanCenter CI

Thanks for the reply @drodri, at least now I know that what I was trying to do is not currently possible

Conan has several other solutions besides ConanCenter, for example you can use the "local-recipes-index" (https://blog.conan.io/2024/04/23/Introducing-local-recipes-index-remote.html) to store your own recipes for your dependencies and share it with other people and use it conveniently as a "remote" in the same way that ConanCenter is used.
